# How to inform parent class about property change

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, parent-child

I have 2 WinForms where one is parent and passing parameter to it's chilf form. The code goes something like this:

```
public class FormMain : Form {
private User user;

public FormMain (User user) {
InitializeComponent();
this.user = user;
}

private void btnUpdateAccount_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            updateUser = new FormUsersUpdate(user);
            updateUser.Show();
        }
}
```

and this:

```
public class FormUsersUpdate(User user){

//Update user in database

}
```

User class have some usual properties like Name, surname, etc. So my question is how to inform parent class about this update without need to again retrieve user from database?

Thanks.

Comment: To inform parent class about what update ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can invoke a callback delegate after the update. In `FormMain`:

```
private void btnUpdateAccount_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    updateUser = new FormUsersUpdate(user, new Action<User>(OnUserUpdated));
    updateUser.Show();
}

private void OnUserUpdated(User user)
{
    // Whatever you wanted to do with the updated user.
}
```

In `FormUsersUpdate`:

```
public class FormUsersUpdate(User user, Action<User> callback)
{
    // Update user, then invoke the callback using the updated user instance,
    // which will call the OnUserUpdated method of the FormMain:
    callback.Invoke(user);
}
```

ShowDialog is mostly a better choice but I never tried it on an mdi child:

```
private void btnUpdateAccount_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    updateUser = new FormUsersUpdate(user);
    updateUser.ShowDialog();

    // Will wait until the user closes the dialog box.
    // FormUserUpdate keeps the updated user in a property called User:
    OnUserUpdated(updateUser.User);
}
```

Comment: Delegates are useful when you want to invoke an event on the parent but isn't needed in this situation.  He is merely wanting to pass the object to the parent.

Comment: @Menefee: Simplest way to achieve this is using the ShowDialog and a property for updated user in the FormUsersUpdate class imho. But using delegates is also a valid solution since calling a delegate is not slower than calling a regular method, I don't think this approach has a considirable drawback.

Comment: @Menefee: And how else the parent will know that the value is changed if I don't invoke a method or a delegate, or raise an event?

Comment: He didn't specify that there would be a need to update something on the parent form.  Only that the user obj needed updated and he didn't want to retrieve it from the database. I would update the CurrentUser object and save the updates to the database on the close of the child window.

Comment: @Menefee: Title of the question is "How to inform parent class about property change". That means he *specified* that there would be a need to update something on the parent form (as I understand it).

Answer (score 3):

Some options:

- Define an event UserUpdated on your second form, and fire the event when any changes occur in the User instance.
- Implement INotifyPropertyChanged on the User class, and handle this event in your main form when fired.

Comment: Defined a delegate and an event on FormUsersUpdate class now I am unable to raise an event. This could be due to the fact that FormUsersUpdate is a partial class.

Comment: See my answers on this question on how to define an event. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12002820/update-view-from-another-view/12003071#12003071

Answer (score 0):

If you are simply wanting to pass the values back then expose them as public static variables in the parent and set them in the child window.

Parent:

```
public static User CurrentUser {get; set;}
```

Child:

```
FormMain.CurrentUser = user;    
FormMain.CurrentUser.LastName = "Menefee";
```

Comment: Not a good use of static fields.. what if you want to create several FormMain ?

Comment: How will the parent know that the `FormUsersUpdate` is done updating and CurrentUser contains the updated value?

Comment: @franssu I would normally agree but given the specifications given this is the simpliest solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working sample for the above issue using delegate and event:

```
public partial class FormUsersUpdate : Form
{
    private readonly User user;
    public delegate void UserChangedEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);
    public event UserChangedEventHandler UsrChanged;

    private void InvokeUsrChanged()
    {
        var args = new EventArgs();
        if (UsrChanged != null) UsrChanged(this, args);
    }

    public FormUsersUpdate()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public FormUsersUpdate(User usr)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.user = usr;
        this.user.name = "Kishore";
    }

    private void FormUsersUpdate_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        InvokeUsrChanged();
    }

}
```

public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private User user;
        FormUsersUpdate _frmusrUpdate;

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.user = new User { name = "Test" };
    }


    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _frmusrUpdate = new FormUsersUpdate(this.user);
        _frmusrUpdate.UsrChanged += new FormUsersUpdate.UserChangedEventHandler(_frmusrUpdate_UsrChanged);
        _frmusrUpdate.Show();
    }

    void _frmusrUpdate_UsrChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("User Details Changed");
    }
}
```